# Ubuntu not showing up in boot order but does show up in BIOS menu. MSI Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, windows

Hey I just installed a fresh Ubuntu on my MSI Laptop alongside windows. When installing Ubuntu I chose this setting:

- Device for bootloader installation: Windows Boot Manager.

Now when I restart my laptop only Windows shows up.

The only way to get to Ubuntu is by pressing F11 and selecting ubuntu.. then I am prompted to the regular GRUB menu.
[image of bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvpKv.jpg)

However when I restart laptop and press DEL to go into boot settings, I cannot find 'ubuntu' in my boot order.. I only see windows boot manager. As seen on this image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS48m.png)

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you do `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @Jos Yes, nothing changed

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs. Both must be installed in same boot mode. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with my MSI motherboard. I am wondering if it's an issue specific to MSI.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and found the solution:
At the bottom of the boot order options, there should be a submenu titled "Hard Disk Drive BBS Priorities"

There you can change the priority of the ubuntu bootloader ahead of windows.